# Connecting Lifx light with Python

Tags: python, lifx

Error importing class from installed package

I've installed and reinstalled lazylights
I've change import to the entire library, but then error: Lifx not defined when creating instance of the class

```
from lazylights import Lifx
import time

lifx = Lifx(num_bulbs=1)  # so it knows how many to wait for when connecting

@lifx.on_connected
def _connected():
    print "Connected!"
```

This yields:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Lifx
```

Comment: How did you install it? Could it be that you installed `lazylights` into a virtual environment, and you aren't in that environment? Have you tried importing just `lazylights` itself?

Comment: pip install lazylights

Comment: i'm using the canopy development environment

Comment: "import lazylights" gives me an error "Lifx global varibale not declared"  in the line lifx=Lifx(num_bulbs=1)

Comment: Does `>>> import lazylights` give you an error?

Comment: not the line itself. I get an error when creating an instance of Lifx. (lifx = Lifx(num_bulbs=1) variable not declared

Comment: Could canopy be missing something I need to install as well? Lifx is a class in the package. I don't know why it's not found